# What determines whether or not you spin out when damaged?

Tags: team-sonic-racing

I recently finished the story mode of Team Sonic Racing and I am still confused about the spin out mechanic.  Sometimes taking damage causes you to spin in a circle and lose all of your speed.  Other times you won't spin and you will only lose a portion of your speed.

What exactly determines whether or not you will spin out when damaged? The reason this matters is some of the challenges require that you don't spin out even once during the race.

My understanding is that the following things should help prevent spin outs but I'm not sure to what degree they actually help.

- Collecting a lot of rings
- Equipping a high defense car configuration
- Playing a power character

I believe power characters are resistant (or immune?) to spinning out when colliding with course obstacles, but that doesn't help with taking damage from wisps.